# Prevent the keyboard from overflowing my LinearLayout after it shows up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

So I'm trying to build a chat app, it works nicely but I got this problem when I'm trying to open the keyboard.
this is how it looks like that without keyboard:

[image: picture1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u34Lq.png)

and this is how it looks like when I click the and the keyboard opens

[image: picture2]

I do want this functionality to stay the same but I would like it to not overflow my LinearLayout

I did this functionality by using this line of code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

here is the xml code for the linearlayout that holds the edittext and the button:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue_bar_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            android:hint="Type a message "
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#A8FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_addMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_bar_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_send_24"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:tint="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If you need some more code, let me know in the comments.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry, is the problem the keyboard hiding the bottom nav-bar?

Comment: No that's fine from me if it's hiding the bottom nav-bar, as you can see the keyboard is slightly the linear layout which holds the edit-text and the button

Comment: I was going to give same answer just was testing out, in the AndroidManifest you can add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" line to the activity and it solves

Comment: It was already android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
the line of java code that he gave works :) 
thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RESIZE` insade of `PAN` this will keep your `EditText` above the SoftKeyboard. here is example -

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

or you can do this with `manifest` file like this -

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
```

it's worked for me in the past, hope it helps.

Comment: It does work! thank you very much unfortunately the nav bar is shown, but it's okay cause the way I did it isn't good :)

Comment: well, I am sure you will fix that, and if you need any other help feel free to ask again, have a great time and happy coding.